# Why am I getting 50 volts instead of 120?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Breaker 10— red wire to switch then to someplace else (don’t know where yet).  Yellow wire from other side of switch to black wire on ceiling light.

Connect meter to white wire on ceiling light to ground and measure 120 volts.

Trace white wire on ceiling light with ohm meter and find it is a white wire (common?) in another nearby box that is not connected to anything in that box.  Connect the meter to the white wire at the light and the common and get 50 volts!

I don’t know what else that common is connected to.  (New old house with lots of bad wiring.)

Why 50 volts?  If that common is not connected to anything except the other end of the light I would expect 0 volts.  If it is connected to the neutral bus I would expect 120 volts. But why 50?

Aren’t all neutrals connected together at the box?

Comment: Pictures of all the items in question, and maybe a rough sketch showing how the pieces fit together would be _most_ helpful. Simply [edit] your post, then drag the pics in - the site will upload and host them for you.

Comment: That is probably leakage, your meter is relative sensitive and is lightly loading the circuit.

Answer (score 4):

You're likely picking up voltage from other circuits that run along side the wires you're testing. Often refered to as "stray voltage", "phantom voltage" or "ghost voltage".  Capacitive coupling between the wires causes some voltage to show up on the unconnected wires.  That wire is acting kind of like an antenna. Here's a random page explaining more: https://www.grainger.com/know-how/safety/electrical-hazard-safety/advanced-electrical-maintenance/kh-ghost-voltages

If there was a load on the circuit, it still wouldn't turn on because there is only a very tiny amount of current available. Some multimeters have a low impedance mode that eliminates those false readings, but that's not common on typical multimeters. Some come as adapters like this one: https://www.amazon.ca/Fluke-SV225-Voltage-Eliminator-Adapter/dp/B005H0NKDC

Comment: Correct, except it's capacitive coupling, formed by long stretches of metal (copper wire) closely spaced, side by side, with no current flowing.

Comment: @P2000 thanks, I just learnt that there is infact a difference between the two. I had thought the terms were pretty much interchangable, but they are slightly different. Corrected.

Comment: On another note, how dangerous is this? I tend to play it on the safe side and turn off the adjacent circuit just to be safe. I don't like my tester going off on a circuit I'm working on...

Comment: @Nelson *IF* it's just stray voltage, it's not typically dangerous.  Don't belive it's even capable of giving you a shock you could feel at all. However, if you're wrong and it's NOT stray voltage, it could be dangerous. Turning off the adjacent circuit is a sensible way to be sure.

Comment: @Grant I have pretty high certainty it is stray voltage because all the circuits are RCBO, so the neutrals can't be crossed without tripping.

Answer (score 0):

Neutral to ground voltage should always be near zero.

"If it is connected to the neutral buss I would expect 120 volts."

The neutral bus is grounded, either in the panelboard or upstream at the meter base or service entrance.  You should never have 120 V in the neutral bus.

Which type of meter are you using?

Is the light working?

Is the light on when you are measuring neutral to ground?

"Trace white wire on ceiling light with ohm meter"

If these wires are connected to the neutral bus then what is accomplished by using an ohm meter?